# Vue - Sharing websocket data across browser tabs

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am having difficulty sending websocket data to multiple tabs. I tried an implementation using the following packages.

- https://github.com/nathantsoi/vue-native-websocket
- https://github.com/xanf/vuex-shared-mutations

Here is my test scenario:

- I open up a single browser tab. I then send data via websocket.  The tab responds correctly and sees the incoming data.
- While the websocket is still sending data, I now open up a second browser tab.  The first tab still sees the data and behaves properly. The second tab does not see the data being sent from the websocket.

myWebsocketExample.js (snippet showing relevant code)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express(); 

app.ws('test', (ws) => {
  ws.on('message', (msg) => {
    ws.send(new Date().toString());
  });
});
app.listen(9000);
```

myStore.js (snippet showing relevant code)

```
import sharedMutations from 'vuex-shared-mutations';
mutations: {
    SOCKET_ONMESSAGE(state, message) {
      console.log(`Received ${message}`);
    },
},
plugins: [sharedMutations({ predicate: ['SOCKET_ONMESSAGE'] })],
```

myTest.vue (snippet showing relevant code)

```
created() {
  this.$store.subscribe((mutation) => {
    if (mutation.type === 'myStore/SOCKET_ONMESSAGE') {
      console.log(`Received via subscription ${mutation.payload}`);
    }
  }
},
```

Am I doing anything fundamentally wrong? Is this the standard pattern for doing this? I'm guessing that this may have something to do with how SOCKET_ONMESSAGE is called within vue-native-websockets as it doesn't seem to get triggered by the other browser tab when using the vuex-shared-mutations.

Answer (score 0):

I removed vuex-shared-mutations and came up with a workaround. I HOPE there is a much better way of achieving this. If so, please let me know!

myStore.js (snippet showing relevant code)

```
import store from '@/store';

function addDataToStore(state, message) {
  // Contains logic to add whatever data you have to the store
}
const channel = new BroadcastChannel('browser-tabs-test');
channel.onmessage = (event) => {
  if (event.data.type === 'myCopy') {
    console.log('This browser tab received a copy of the original data);
    // Call a mutation so a class that is subscribed (aka this.$store.subscribe) 
    // will be alerted that this store instance has been updated with this data
    store.commit('myStore/SOCKET_ONMESSAGE_COPY', event.data.message);
  }
};
mutations: {
    SOCKET_ONMESSAGE(state, message) {
      console.log(`Received ${message}`);
      channel.postMessage({ type: 'myCopy', message });
      addDataToStore(state, message);
    },
    // Having a similar but separate mutation avoids infinite loops that 
    // would occur with the broadcast channel posting messages
    SOCKET_ONMESSAGE_COPY(state, message) {          
      console.log(`Received Copy of ${message}`);
      addDataToStore(state, message);
    },
},
```

myTest.vue (snippet showing relevant code)

```
created() {
  this.$store.subscribe((mutation) => {
    if (mutation.type === 'myStore/SOCKET_ONMESSAGE' ||
        mutation.type === 'myStore/SOCKET_ONMESSAGE_COPY'
    ) {
      console.log(`Received via subscription ${mutation.payload} from ${mutation.type}`);
      // Do something with the payload in this instance of the class
    }
  }
},
```

When using this code:

- browser tab #1 only receives SOCKET_ONMESSAGE events and
- browser tab #2 only receives SOCKET_ONMESSAGE_COPY events